# How did 'how' + 'ever' = 'however' ⟹ 'but'?

Tags: etymology, morphology

> [ [OED:](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/89020?redirectedFrom=however#eid) ] Etymology:  < [how adv.](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/89004#eid1371396) + [ever adv. 8e.](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/65307#eid5134695)
>
> 3. Qualifying a sentence or clause as a whole: For all that, nevertheless, notwithstanding; yet; = *but* at the beginning of the sentence.
>
> [[ever adv. 8e.](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/65307#eid5134695) :]    Appended to relative pronouns or advbs., and giving to them a generalized or indefinite force; = Latin *-cumque*. These combinations are now always written as single words: see [howsoever adv.](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/89040#eid1379101), [whosoever pron.](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/228809#eid14429814), etc.

How did the Compounding of the adverbs 'how' and 'ever' (into 'however') imply or produce  meaning 3 above for 'however'? I ask not about the other meanings of 'however' here.

OED specified the pertinent definition (among the many) for 'ever' , but unhelpfully not for 'how'.

Comment: You probably *do* need to consider the other meanings of 'however'. It seems to me paraphrasings such as ***nevertheless, on the other hand, by contrast*** can be using interchangeably with ***however*** regardless of whether the context is *However OP disagrees* or *OP however disagrees* (I don't care if you want to add commas). Perhaps the issue is really a matter of why ***but*** doesn't have the same flexibility, rather than why ***however*** can be used in both contexts.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thanks for your comment. Yes; you are correct about the `need to consider the other meanings of 'however', and your last sentence. Please feel free to edit my post or repost your last sentence as a separate question (and inform me afterwards!).

Answer (score 3):

You have quoted only part of the OED's etymology for *however*; in addition to the main body of the etymology, it also has an "etymological note". The full etymology is:

> **Etymology:**  < [<sub><sup>HOW</sup></sub> *adv.*](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/89004#eid1371396) + [<sub><sup>EVER</sup></sub> *adv.* 8e](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/65307#eid5134695).
>   <sub>In senses 2, 3, *however* is the relic of an original subordinate clause (like those of sense 1), such as ‘however this may be’.</sub>

In other words, senses 2 and 3 don't come from *how* and *-ever* directly; rather, they are shortened forms of expressions like "however this may be", with the "this may be" part being left implicit.

Comment: Thanks. I will add this to my OP, but your answer only generates a further question: How does ‘however this may be’ produce definition 3 above?

Comment: I don't think it's appropriate to take the answer to your initial question and use it to change your question into a different question. That's [moving the goalposts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_the_goalposts). If you want to ask how "however this may be" means "in spite of this", you should post that as a separate question.

Comment: What do you think of moving your answer as a comment? I did modify my question because it appears more efficient than posting another one, and because the problem with the question was not linguistical, but rather was my oversight of something in the dictionary.

Comment: @LePressentiment: My answer was not a comment; it was an answer to the question as it stood. (And it's not an appropriate comment now, either; if it's to be interpreted as a comment of the form "there's a problem with your question", then it should simply be deleted as soon as the problem is addressed.)

Comment: @ruakh As requested, I will post a new separate question then and reinstate the original question.